# How to paste columns vertically to columns with unequal number of characters

Tags: cut-copy-paste

We have two separate files:

**f1.txt**

```
17.0,
155.7,
1123,9,
```

and

**f2.txt**

```
1
2
3
```

After opening files vertically with `vim -O ~/f1.txt ~/f2.txt`

**How to obtain?**

```
17.0,1
155.7,2
1123,9,3
```

which is the equivalent of `paste -d '' f1.txt f2.txt` in bash

---

I tried all I could but in the end I got:

```
17.0,1
155.72,
1123,39,
```

So the column was pasted vertically but not appended to the end of the existing line.

Comment: I'm guessing you won't accept `:!paste -d '' f1.txt f2.txt` as an answer? ;)

Comment: `:set virtualedit=all`, paste the column somewhere to the right, then `:%s/,\s*//`. :)

Answer (score 9):

I have answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050503/164835 
But that question is not exactly same as this one, so I answer here once again:

in **File1** do:

- `:%right`
- `0<ctrl-v>G$` -> column select all
- `y` -> yank

in **File2** do:

- `P` -> paste
- `:%left`

**Done**!

It is pure vim solution, and goes pretty easy,  looks like:

[image]

Comment: Using `:left` and `:right` is pretty clever actually!

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather use the `paste` command line tool, if you are using Linux/BSD/OSX:

```
paste -d '' f1.txt f2.txt
```

should do what you want. You can also read the result into the current vi buffer with `:r!paste -d '' f1.txt f2.txt`.

Vim's block-visual mode can be very useful but for CSV-ish data, I'd recommend `paste` or [chrisbra/csv.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim).

Comment: It would be better if the answer is specific to vim

Comment: @SibiCoder Please define "better".

Answer (score 2):

Using a macro:

```
qq<c-w><c-w>y$<c-w><c-w>$p+<c-w><c-w>+<c-w><c-w>q2@q
```

1. `qq`: Start recording a macro,
2. `<c-w><c-w>`: Switch to second window,
3. `y$`: yank the contents of the line,
4. `<c-w><c-w>`: Switch back to first window,
5. `$p`: Paste at the end of the line,
6. `+<c-w><c-w>+<c-w><c-w>`: Move down a line in both windows,
7. `q`: End the recording,
8. `2@q`: Replay the recording twice.

Answer (score 2):

And here is another solution, probably not the most efficient one or the cleaner one but I had some time to make some vimscript:

```
function! PasteAtEndOfLine()
    " Check that the selection is blockwise
    if ( getregtype('"')[0] != '' )
        echo "not blockwise"
        return
    endif

    " Get the selection and split it on new lines
    let regcontent = getreg('"')
    let lines = split(regcontent, '\n')

    " Save the cursor position and the current line
    let save_cursor = getpos('.')
    let line_number = save_cursor[1]

    " For each line add the content of the register at the end
    " And go to next line
    for line in lines
        execute "normal A" . line
        let line_number += 1
        call setpos('.', [0, line_number, 0, 0])
    endfor

    " Restore the initial position
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endfunction
```

To use it you should:

- Visually select block wise the lines you want to paste from f2.txt: <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
- Yank the text to the unnamed register: <kbd>y</kbd>
- Go to the first line of f1.txt
- Call the function: `:call PasteAtEndOfLine()`
- You're done

Comment: Same idea, but using `sub-replace-special :s\=`: `:'<,'>s/$/\=getreg('"',1,1)[line("'<")-line('.')]`