# How to paste/merge 2 blocks of text in vim

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste, macro

I search a way to paste/merge 2 block of text

block A

```
apple
pear
banana
```

block B

```
tomato
beans
potato
```

to this

```
apple tomato
pear beans
banana potato
```

I'm looking for an easy way to do this using macros.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to paste columns vertically to columns with unequal number of characters](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9239/how-to-paste-columns-vertically-to-columns-with-unequal-number-of-characters)

Comment: That question is about merging two files (thus suggestions to use the GNU `paste` command). OP didn't mention files so my answer is about two blocks of text in a buffer (or two buffers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual block mode is a good route....

1. Put cursor on "a" in apple
2. `<C-V>` : we'll visually select the whole block...
3. move cursor to banana, e.g. `}k` is good (line count agnostic)
4. `$A<space><esc>` - this adds a space after every line
5. `gvd` - `gv` recreates the previous visual selection, `d` deletes

Move cursor to "t" in tomato and hit `P` to paste.

This can be used directly in a macro.

**Update:** I just remembered that I wrote a fairly substantial answer to a somewhat similar question: [Add a block of text to end of lines](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16094/add-a-block-of-text-to-end-of-lines/16097#16097). It doesn't have an exact answer to your question like I've written here but you might find it useful/interesting.

Comment: I tried that but when I paste I end up with, is it something wrong with my paste command?

tomato
apple
pear
banana
beans
potato

Comment: You pasted with capital `P`? Cursor first column, first line of second block?

Comment: if i use capital p it goes
apple
pear
banana
tomato
beans
potato

Comment: I got it here... tks

Comment: This works great but creates two distinct columns, creating extra spaces. I think @MatheusCampos only wants one space between each word. If this is the case, use something like this to replace every sequence of "several spaces" with "one space", after selecting the lines you need: `:s/\ \+/ /`

Comment: @Biggybi It shouldn't. When I run it it looks exactly like his example.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on then, I just tried with vanilla vim (`vim -u NONE -U NONE -N`) and had the behaviour I described...

Comment: While that configuration's good for debugging problems it's not really representative of the most common setups. A better test would probably be to use Vim's defaults.vim as the sole config file. Just use `--clean`. Either way when I get a sec I'll see if I can reproduce what you're seeing.